# Python Date Format

Tags: python

In my csv data I have the date format like this **1/31/2017** which is the expected python format of **mm/dd/yyyy**.

But with the dataset when I run the python code it shows the date format is not valid. So could anyone please help me with the problem pf this date format.

Error shown by python pycharm IDE:

> ValueError: time data 1/1/2017 doesn't match format specified

Comment: Post sample data, otherwise it will be difficult for anyone to help

Comment: Does the answer helped ??

Comment: This is my code

Comment: import geoplotlib
from geopy import geocoders
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandas as pd
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
g = geocoders.GoogleV3(api_key='google_map_api_key_here')
def do_geocode(address):
    try:
        return g.geocode(address, timeout=10)
    except GeocoderTimedOut:
        return do_geocode(address, timeout=10)
df = pd.read_csv('data\data - Copy.csv')
df['FL_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FL_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
airline = df.set_index('FL_DATE')

Comment: My data is 1/31/2017 NK 972 PHX Phoenix, AZ DFW Dallas/Fort Worth, TX 159 -6 513 1 0  0 127 134 115 868 9 10

Comment: kumar: change the format from %Y-%m-%d to what I have given in my answer and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you have not processed your date correctly. Try this on your df:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('1/31/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
```